# What are the criteria for convergence of an integral?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

We know that $$P=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}$$ is Divergent, since at $x=0$ integrand is undefined.

Also $$Q=\int_{0}^{\pi}\lfloor\cot (x)\rfloor d x$$ is divergent based on the author below.

[How to compute the integral $ \int_0^\pi \lfloor\cot (x)\rfloor dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081351/how-to-compute-the-integral-int-0-pi-lfloor-cot-x-rfloor-dx)

Whereas $$R=\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\:dx$$ is also divergent.

So does it mean the integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is divergent if either $a$ or $b$ or both not in the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: No. For example, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx$ is convergent even though $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not at all. If $f$ is undefined at $0$, it may still makes sense to talk about $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$; it's simply$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_\varepsilon^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$For instance\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}2-2\sqrt\varepsilon\\&=2.\end{align}

Comment: So in that case we have $\int_{0}^{1}\ln x\:dx=\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_{t}^{1}\ln x\:dx=-1-\lim_{t \to 0^+ }t\ln t=-1$ so it converges?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.